# My plots are blank, and I don't get any errors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from scipy.stats import norm
import pylab 
import scipy.stats as stats

def filtered_historical_simulation_VAR_ES(df,l,weights,windowsize):
    VaR975ex = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))
    ES975ex = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))
    VaR99ex = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))
    ES99ex = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))    
    VaR975 = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))
    ES975 = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))
    VaR99 = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))
    ES99 = np.zeros(len(df['NASDAQ']))    
    df['NASDAQ'] = np.array(df['NASDAQ'])
    df['AEXUSD'] = np.array(df['AEX'] + df['EUR/USD'])
    df['DAXUSD'] = np.array(df['DAX'] + df['EUR/USD'])
    df['Nikkei'] = np.array(df['Nikkei'])
    df['EURIBOR'] = np.array(df['EURIBOR'])
    risks = ['NASDAQ','AEXUSD','DAXUSD','Nikkei','EURIBOR']
    scenarios = np.zeros((len(df['NASDAQ']),len(risks)))
    mvols = np.zeros((len(df['NASDAQ']),len(risks)))
    mresids = np.zeros((len(df['NASDAQ']),len(risks)))
    for j in range(len(risks)):
        mvols[0:windowsize,j] = np.std(np.array(df[risks[j]])[0:windowsize],ddof=1)
    for i in range(windowsize-1,len(df['NASDAQ'])-1):
        mvols[i+1,j] = np.sqrt(l*mvols[i,j]**2+(1-l)*df.iloc[i][risks[j]]**2)
    for j in range(len(risks)):
        for i in range(len(df['NASDAQ'])):
            mresids[i,j] = df.iloc[i][risks[j]]/(mvols[i,j])
    for i in range(len(risks)):
        df[risks[i]+'vol'] = mvols[:,i]
        df[risks[i]+'residuals'] = mresids[:,i]

    for i in range(windowsize,len(scenarios)):
        for k in range(len(scenarios)):
            for j in range(len(risks)):
                scenarios[k,j] = 1-np.exp(mresids[k,j]*mvols[i,j])
    portfolio = scenarios@weights
    sorted_portfolio = sorted(portfolio[i-windowsize:i])
    
    VaR975[i] = sorted_portfolio[-math.ceil(25*(len(sorted_portfolio))/1000)]
    if portfolio[i] > VaR975[i]:
        VaR975ex[i] = portfolio[i]
    else:
        VaR975ex[i] = None
    ES975[i] = np.average(sorted_portfolio[-math.ceil(25*(len(sorted_portfolio))/1000):])
    if portfolio[i] > ES975[i]:
        ES975ex[i] = portfolio[i]
    else:
        ES975ex[i] = None    
    VaR99[i] = sorted_portfolio[-math.ceil(10*(len(sorted_portfolio))/1000)]
    if portfolio[i] > VaR99[i]:
        VaR99ex[i] = portfolio[i]
    else:
        VaR99ex[i] = None
    ES99[i] = np.average(sorted_portfolio[-math.ceil(10*(len(sorted_portfolio))/1000):])
    if portfolio[i] > ES99[i]:
        ES99ex[i] = portfolio[i]
    else:
       ES99ex[i] = None
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax[0, 0].plot(VaR975[windowsize:])
ax[0, 0].plot(VaR975ex[windowsize:],'.')
ax[1, 0].plot(VaR99[windowsize:])
ax[1, 0].plot(VaR99ex[windowsize:],'.')
ax[0, 1].plot(ES975[windowsize:])
ax[0, 1].plot(ES975ex[windowsize:],'.')
ax[1, 1].plot(ES99[windowsize:])
ax[1, 1].plot(ES99ex[windowsize:],'.')
ax[0, 0].title.set_text('VaR 97.5')
ax[1, 0].title.set_text('VaR99')
ax[0, 1].title.set_text('ES975')
ax[1, 1].title.set_text('ES99')
fig.suptitle('Filtered historic simulation', fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('filteredHistoricsim.png')

main
#def main():
     filename = 'stocks.csv'
     df = pd.read_csv('stocks.csv')
     portfolio_size = 1000000
     start_date = '2011-04-27'
     weights = [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]
     weights = [weight*portfolio_size for weight in weights]
     l = 0.99
     windowsize = 500
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code and it doesn't show the plots.
I have imported the data which is indices, NASDAQ, DAX, AEX, Nikkei, EURIBOR , made all the variables and the plots are showing blank:

[image]

I am trying to plot the value at risk and expected shortfall.

Comment: have you verified the values in those arrays like `VaR975[windowsize:]` and `ES975[windowsize:]`? maybe they're all `nan` for example

Comment: yes i have verified those, they are all numbers and no values are missing

Comment: If you don't have sample data, it is hard to prepare for it. If you have toy data, you will be more motivated to answer. Please try to provide sample data next time. The indentation of `sorted_portfolio = sorted(portfolio[i-windowsize:i])` line is not correct, is it? And if I commented out the if statement in the second half of the function, the graph would be displayed. (It's just a graph of horizontal lines.) Do you need a return value?
I still need to make sure that I am getting the data that I intend.

Comment: How long are your data sets compared to the window size (500)?  The limits you are getting are the auto-limits if you give Matplotlib _empty_ data (e.g `plt.plot([])`) or all invalid (nan or inf) data.  My suspicion is that there is a bug in your processing code.